# EPPlus Excel Related Dates Last Modified

Tags: c#, excel, epplus, epplus-4

Does anyone know if there is a way to set the "Last Modified" date of a workbook?  You can see this property by opening an .xlsx and going File -> Info in Excel, it's under Related Dates and it is not set by default with EPPlus.  If you simply save the file in Excel afterwards the date is then populated.  Is there any way to set this date with EPPlus when generating the file originally?

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, this can be done by setting the Workbook.Properties.Modified of the ExcelPackage you're working on.